# activate javascript animation when on view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I use an animantion to animate bar with percent, but it's in javascript, i have already seen the answer to do it for CSS animation, but i don't find anything to activate the animation when the user get to the section with the bar.

With my code the animation loads at the same moment when the page is loading, i need to make it loads when the content is on view because it will not be the first section and there is no point to animate it if the user can't see it.

Thanks for helping i let you a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cju4jf20/#&togetherjs=KcitS1cGgb)**

this is my javascript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
        }, 2500);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's working for me check the **[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cju4jf20/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me. To achieve that you want use [Lasy Load](https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```

```css
#home {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: wheat;
}
#skills {
  background-color: lightslategrey;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding-top: 5%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.container-skillbar {
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: none;
}
.skillbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -ms-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
}
.skillbar-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #6adcfa;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.skillbar-title span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.skillbar-bar {
  height: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.skill-bar-percent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section id="home">

  </section>

  <section id="skills">
    <h1>Mes compétences</h1>
    <div class="container-skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="75%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #186998;"><span>Photoshop</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2697d8;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Ende Skill Bar -->

      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="70%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #aa631d;"><span>Illustrator</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #e17d1a;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">70%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Ende Skill Bar -->

      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="50%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #a52b7b;"><span>Indesign</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #df3fa8;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">50%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Ende Skill Bar -->

      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="65%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #821c83;"><span>Premiere</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #b91ebb;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">65%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Ende Skill Bar -->

      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="45%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #611983;"><span>After Effect</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #a726e3;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">45%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Ende Skill Bar -->

      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="75%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #e34e26;"><span>HTML5</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #f16528;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
      </div>

      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="50%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #016fba;"><span>CSS3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2aa9e0;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">50%</div>
      </div>

      <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="35%">
        <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #16337e;"><span>Jquery</span>
        </div>
        <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #1d45aa;"></div>
        <div class="skill-bar-percent">35%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Ende Skill Bar -->
    </div>
    <!-- Ende container Skill Bar -->
  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: i know this works but actually i have a section before this one, and the skills section is not on screen when you're on the site, it's when the user scroll to it that i want it to be animated :)

Comment: how other code loaded after scroll? Have you use any lazy load?

Comment: then `DOM` `ready` do all things. that binds `animate` after html loaded. What problem you are facing?

Comment: can you explain more ? :)

Comment: You have to use [Lasy Load](https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/) for achieve this. check its demo.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
var check_is_in_view = function(elm){
    var bounds = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    return bounds.top < window.innerHeight && bounds.bottom > 0;
}
var your_element = document.getElementById("foo");
var result = check_is_in_view(your_element);
console.log(result);
```

Hope, thats help.

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/0pj91p2z/

Comment: foo is just a name.in your
case :

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.skillbar').each(function() {

  if (check_is_in_view($(this))) {
   // Animate
   $(this).animate({
    width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
   }, 2500);

  } else {
    // Do nothing
  }
  
 });
});